# Ran a logistic regression and calculated the probabilities but they appear too high

Tags: r, regression, probability, logistic, odds

I ran a logistic regression in R using driving data from about 10,000 people. The model included age, years of driving experience, as well as 4 driving test results. The dependent variable was whether or not they had been involved in a crash recently (yes or no, a categorical variable).

The coefficients of the model are given below:

```
                    Estimate     Std.Err       z value     Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)        -1.450041     0.207144      -7.000      2.56e-12 ***
riding experience  -0.014115     0.003697      -3.818      0.000134 ***
age                -0.034544     0.003608      -9.575       < 2e-16 ***
test 1              0.261485     0.088645       2.950      0.003180 ** 
test 2              0.090102     0.051328       1.755      0.079184 .  
test 3              0.228918     0.073666       3.108      0.001887 ** 
test 4              0.070106     0.063652       1.101      0.270729
```

Firstly, with 10,000 people am I right in thinking that p-values aren't going to be that useful?

I calculated the probabilities of being involved in a crash with a 1 unit increase in each variable by doing `exp(variable)` to get the odds and then, `probability = odds/(1+odds)`. It gave me:

```
(Intercept)        0.1899952          
ridingexp          0.4964712
age                0.4913648
test 1             0.5650012
test 2             0.5225104
test 3             0.5569810   
test 4             0.5175193
```

These seem awfully high! It is like saying that an increase in age of 1 year makes you 49% less likely to be involved in a crash? Surely that can't be right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the mistake you are making is the connection between the coefficients and the probability.

Defining the linear predictor (i.e. the estimated log odds) as

$\eta = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + ...$

You are right that $\exp(\beta_1)$ represents the fold difference in odds associated with a one unit increase in $x_1$. So for age, a one year increase in age is associated with a exp(-0.0345) = 0.966 fold change in the odds of being in an accident. As you expected, not a huge difference.

It appears that you just took 0.966 as the odds and converted this to a probability. This was the fundamental mistake: 0.996 is not the odds, but the multiplicative difference in odds.

I assume you want to go back to the probability scale because that's the scale that's most natural to you. However, it's not so simple to convert a change in the odds to a change in the probability; how much the change a multiplicative change in the odds changes the probability (on the multiplicative scale) is *not* constant, but rather depends on the current value of the odds.

For example, suppose we have that the base odds are 1, and multiply this by 2. The corresponding probabilities are 1/(1 + 1) = 1/2 and 2/(2+1) = 2/3. Now suppose our base odds are 2 and we multiply this by 2. The corresponding probabilities are 2/(2+1) = 2/3 and 4/(4+1) = 4/5.

So it's not so simple to summarize a change in the odds on the probability scale.

Answer (score 2):

As @CliffAB mentions, interpreting changes in the odds on the predicted probabilities scale can be tough. But this is where graphing comes in handy. For instance, let's generate some data following a simple version of the model you provided, then estimate the model:

```
set.seed(2)
n <- 1000
experience <- rnorm(n)
age <- sample(16:99, n, replace=TRUE)
z <- -1.45 + (-0.01 * experience) + (-0.03 * age)
y <- rbinom(n, 1, plogis(z))
mod <- glm(y ~ experience + age, family="binomial")
summary(mod)

Call:
glm(formula = y ~ experience + age, family = "binomial")

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-0.5963  -0.3857  -0.2556  -0.1709   3.0434  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -1.085033   0.332718  -3.261  0.00111 ** 
experience  -0.016846   0.140535  -0.120  0.90459    
age         -0.037357   0.007272  -5.137 2.79e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 402.9  on 999  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 370.5  on 997  degrees of freedom
AIC: 376.5

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
```

We can then extract the predicted probabilities for each data point in our data set with the `predict` function (here just looking at the first 6 observations):

```
> head(predict(mod, type="response"))
         1          2          3          4          5          6 
0.02194610 0.02319195 0.01355816 0.04226472 0.09935722 0.06117067
```

Using `type="response"` is the same as taking the linear predictor with `predict` and running it through `plogis`:

```
> head(cbind(predict(mod, type="response"),
+            plogis(predict(mod))))
        [,1]       [,2]
1 0.02194610 0.02194610
2 0.02319195 0.02319195
3 0.01355816 0.01355816
4 0.04226472 0.04226472
5 0.09935722 0.09935722
6 0.06117067 0.06117067
```

Now, we can plot the predicted probability of having an accident at different ages, according to our data set:

```
> plot(age, predict(mod, type="response"), ylab="Predicted Probability")
```

[image]

However, this doesn't keep `experience` constant, so we can create a new data set of "covariate profiles" we may be interested in, where the only thing that changes is `age`, holding `experience` at its mean:

```
new <- data.frame("(Intercept)"=1,
                  "experience"=mean(experience),
                  "age"=16:99)

plot(predict(mod, newdata=new, type="response"), type="l", lwd=2, col="red",
     ylab="Predicted Probability")
```

[image]